# How to update leaflet markers for every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, marker

I am working on a Leaflet map and markers.

I am getting markers latlng from JSON and showing it correctly.

```
getLatLng()

function getLatLng() {
  var details = '/equipment/api/getLatLong';
  $.ajax({
    url: details,
    method: 'get'
  }).done(function(response) {

    $('.subSection').html('').append('<section><button type="button" onclick="hideEquipmentDetails()"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></section>');
    var equipmentDetails = response.data.filters;
    console.log(equipmentDetails)
    $.each(equipmentDetails, function(i, value) {
      L.marker([value.latitude, value.longitude]).addTo(map).bindPopup('<b><span> Name:</span>' + value.name + '</b>');
    })
  });
}

setInterval(function() {
  getLatLng();
}, 5000)
```

I am refreshing the method for every 5 seconds.

So I need to show the markers in updated latlng and old markers should be hidden.

```
setInterval(function() {
  //L.marker.setOpacity(0);
  //L.markerClusterGroup()
  //markers.clearLayers();
  //map.removeLayer(L.marker);
  //markers.removeLayer()
  //L.marker().removeTo(map);
  getLatLng();
}, 5000)
```

I tried every options to achieve this but I couldn't.

Is there any other way to do it?

Otherwise should I define one more array to store the initial latlng values then to check each time whether latlng is changed or not (in this scenario I can replace only updated latlng markers right?No need to replace all markers every time right?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of instantiating a new marker on every update, you could simply modify its position using its [`setLatLng()`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker-setlatlng) method.

The usual implementation is to use a "global" marker variable (just in a scope outside your update function is enough), initialize it to a Marker on your first iteration, then instead of instantiating a new one, simply modify its position.

The possibly slightly trickier part is to manage several markers at the same time. You need some sort of identification mean to know which one to update. I assume it is your `value.name`:

```
var markers = {}; // Dictionary to hold your markers in an outer scope.

function ajaxCallback(response) {
  var equipmentDetails = response.data.filters;
  $.each(equipmentDetails, function(i, value) {
    var id = value.name;
    var latLng = [value.latitude, value.longitude];
    var popup = '<b><span> Name:</span>' + id + '</b>';

    if (!markers[id]) {
      // If there is no marker with this id yet, instantiate a new one.
      markers[id] = L.marker(latLng).addTo(map).bindPopup(popup);
    } else {
      // If there is already a marker with this id, simply modify its position.
      markers[id].setLatLng(latLng).setPopupContent(popup);
    }
  });
}

$.ajax({
  url: details,
  method: 'get'
}).done(ajaxCallback);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much.. now which method do I need to refresh for every 5 seconds

Comment: Your same `getLatLng` that wraps your AJAX call. It is probably faster for you to try and see, rather than asking for trivial help.

Comment: one more help pls pls. am getting popup on `onclick` now.But I want it on `onhover` of marker.what I need to change in my code?pls pls last help?

Comment: Try tooltip instead of popup. It is much easier than forcing openPopup on marker mouseover

Comment: is it impossible to show popup on marker mouse over?

Comment: It _is_ possible, but you have to implement it yourself, whereas it is built-in with [tooltip](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#tooltip). If you do want to implement it, have a search here on SO, I am sure you will find plenty posts about it.